# Numpy Softmax - The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, softmax

I am using a softmax function in getting an output from a neural network and getting the minimum value as the output in calculating the error.

However if the output is all the same assuming [0,0,0] the output of the softmax function is [0.33,0.33,0.33]

So when selecting the minimum from this like,

```
output = softmax(np.dot(hs,HO))
tarminout = np.subtract(target,output)
mine = min(tarminout)
mine = 0.5 * np.power(mine,2)
finalError += mine
```

It gives the following error because there are more than one equal minimum values,

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>      File "ann.py", line 234, in module
>
> learn()
>      File "ann.py", line 97, in learn
>
> mine = min(tarminout)
>
> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

How can I get pass this when there are more than 1 equal minimum values by  selecting just one of them?

Thanks

Comment: Clearly, you are leaving something out. What you are describing should work. Please post the code you are actually using and the full error trace.

Comment: I added some details, the problem is there are more than one equal minimum values, that's what's causing this so the min value can't select one because there are more than one.

Comment: No, it's not. try `min(np.array([1,1,1]))` The problem is elsewhere. Again, why don't you post the full error trace.

Comment: What is the type of `tarminout`? Is it a 2D array?

Comment: That target is something like [0,1,0,0] the output is the output of the NN something like [0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1] so tarminout is the difference between the two arrays.

Comment: @rksh `target = numpy.array([0,1,0,0]); output = numpy.array([0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.1]); tarminout = numpy.subtract(target, output); min(tarminout)` ← this returns -0.5 as expected.

Comment: @rksh You'll get that error in the call to `min(tarminout)` if `tarminout` is a 2D (or higher dimensional) array.  What is `tarminout.shape`?  And what are the shapes of `target` and `output`?

Comment: Isn't there a numpy version of `min` or `minimum`?

Answer (score 2):

The answer's buried in the comments above: your error is likely the result of passing a multi-dimensional ndarray to the standard python min(), which doesn't understand them.

Way #1: call np.min instead of min

Way #2 (not recommended): flatten your array, min(tarminout.ravel())

Way #1 is preferred, use numpy operators on numpy arrays